# Python automation script should run when any code change in a file

Tags: python, automation, pycharm

I want to run my automation script in python only when there is a code change in a different folder. How do I detect the change and run the script?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `os.path.getmtime` to know when the file was last modified, and constantly check this time.

Something like this:

```
import os.path, time

last_time = time.ctime(os.path.getmtime(file))
while(True):
    if time.ctime(os.path.getmtime(file)) != last_time:
        print('Script changed!')
        #do what u want...
        break
    time.sleep(10)
```

Answer (score 1):

You you want to monitor file changes in a directory, I hardly recommend using [Watchdog](https://pypi.org/project/watchdog/).

Watchdog comes with a script `watchmedo` which can run shell scripts on file change.

You can try something like that:

```sh
watchmedo shell-command \
    --patterns="*.py" \
    --recursive \
    --command='path/to/python path/to/script.py "${watch_src_path}"' \
    your_directory
```